# Python Replace Dataframe Value If Equal to String

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to isolate the latest file in my directory, and mark any rows coming from that file in my dataframe as "Latest".

So essentially, I'll have my source column say "pipeline-03-01-2020.xlsx", "pipeline-02-01-2020.xlsx", "pipeline-01-01-2020.xlsx", and I am looking for a line of code to highlight "pipeline-03-01-2020.xlsx" = the latest file, and replace the values within the Source column: "pipeline-03-01-2020.xlsx" --> "This Week" and leave the rest the same... What is wrong with my line below?

```
list_of_files = glob.glob(link_pipe2) # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

pipeline['Source'] = pipeline['Source'].apply(lambda x: 'This Week' if latest_file in x else pipeline['Source'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = pipeline['Source'] == latest_fname
pipeline[mask]['Source'] = "This Week"
```

is how I would approach this

Answer (score 0):

You can use .replace on your source column which should do the job.

pipeline['source'].replace(to_replace=latest_file, value='This Week', inplace=True)